# Data Transformation Question - Multiplying data proportional to demographics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, data-transformation

I have a bunch of data that is tied to demographic variables (Age, Sex, Income, Education, etc.). However, the data is sent by one person in a household for the entire house. It's numerical data and I wish to separate the data proportional to each person to make it so if you're a Male aged 40, you get a numerical output different than a Female aged 21.

This begins my problem, right now we have a "hypothesis" of how the variables affect the output. Thus, we start there and whenever someone sends data, we make the proportions based on our hypothesis then run some regression to see if anything changed. So if we believe an University educated, aged 40 Male gives 107.4 as an output and a High-school educated, aged 19 Female gives 76 then if they lived in the same house, we can "give" more of the numerical data to the Male instead of the female in a proportional manner. For this to work, we would need a lot of varied data from different demographics however.

Basically, I'd love to know if there's a better method out there for deciding proportions and updating the new data based on that. Thanks

Comment: Google for "survey weights", there is a huge literature on this topic.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that there is an [error in variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) problem. Eg. let's say the output variable $y$ you care about is cancer, $x$ is cigarette usage, and your data is collected at the household level. Individuals who dont' smoke may get a positive $x_i$ value (because someone else in the household does smoke) and individuals that do smoke may get a too low value (if other members don't smoke or smoke less). Your *true* $x_i$ will be measured with error, and hence error in variables...